# EF Core delete on table violates foreign key constraint on table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two tables (`Device` and `PropertyValue`) and when I try to delete a `Device` I get an exception saying:

> violates foreign key

I also tried to set the cascade on `OnModelCreating()`, but still not work.

```
public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyValue> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? DeviceId { get; set; }
    public Device Device { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyValue>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Device)
    .WithMany(b => b.Properties)
    .HasForeignKey(w => w.DeviceId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

**EDIT**: I am using a repository but basally I am deleting using `_context.Devices.Remove(entity);`

Comment: Please show the code you use to delete the Device entity.

Comment: For a straight relational nature that would make sense. You have a record in PropertyValue with the Device.Id that you are trying to delete.

Comment: *"I also tried to set the cascade on OnModelCreating()"* Did you generate migration and update the database after that? Because cascade delete is expected to be performed by the database.

Comment: @IvanStoev it actually solved it!
If you create an answer I will be happy to accept it :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the FK property `DeviceId` is nullable, the relationship is [optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships), which by [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#cascade-delete) has delete cascade turned off.

So adding `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` is step in the right direction.

But if you haven't done that initially and have already created your tables and relationships, you have to make sure it's applied in the database as well (because for cascade delete EF relies in general to be implemented by the database), by generating new migration and updating the database.

Answer (score 2):

If the related entities in the Properties collection are not loaded and tracked by the context, they will not be deleted. The recommended approach is to set a cascade action on the foreign key constraint in the database as well, as described in the documentation for DeleteBehavior:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.deletebehavior

If you create the schema automatically with EF, this is also what will be generated.